# Corrupt USB RAW filesystem showing wrong size

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk, raw

I am trying to fix this USB stick for a friend who ripped it out of their computer incorrectly resulting in the filesystem being destroyed to the max, and the device showing a capacity which is clearly wrong. 
I brought up Testdisk to see if this would help me recover the partitions on the disk, but that just gave me this:

[image]

And when i try to go into it and do a scan it comes back with nothing of use.

Is there any way to recover this device or is this the result of a physical fault on the device which is beyond any repair?

Comment: I am not an expert in data recovery, but in the few times I have tried, if TestDisk can't see the drive size correctly then there is something in the flash or the controller that is damaged and it cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fix hardware damage using software. Given that the controller reports a totally wrong size, the drive is physically damaged.

Just throw it away.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the case. Just wanted confirmation from people better qualified than myself. Thanks for providing it :)